# If $M_g : f \to gf$ from $L^p(\Omega,\mu)$ into itself , show $\|M_g\|=\|g\|_{L^\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, solution-verification

If $1 \le p \le \infty$ and let $g : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be any measurable function s.t. $g \in L^\infty(\Omega,\mu)$, prove that the multiplication operator $M_g : f \to gf$ from $L^p(\Omega,\mu)$ into itself is bounded and has norm equal $\|g\|_{L^\infty}$.

Solution:

Let $\|g\|_{L^\infty} = K$, since $f\in {L^p}$ then to show that the operator is bounded

$$\|M_gf\|_{L^p} =  \|gf\|_{L^p}=\Big(\int_\Omega |gf|^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}\le \Big(\int_\Omega |Kf|^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}\le K .\|f\|_{L^p} < \infty  \ \ \ \ (\ast)$$

Also by def. we'd have

$$\|M_g\| = \inf \{c>0 : \|M_gf\|_{L^p}\le c . \|f\|_{L^p}\} = K = \|g\|_{L^\infty} \ \ \ \ \ \  \square $$

$\\$

Is above correct?

Is so, I saw in the solution that the $\|M_g\|= K = \|g\|_{L^\infty}$ was concluded as follows, which I cannot understand why it is better to do like below rather than the above:

1- $(\ast) \implies \|M_g\|\le K$

2- Trying to conclude that $\forall \epsilon>0$, we can show $\|M_gf\|_{L^p}\ge (K-\epsilon)\|f\|_{L^p} \implies \|M_g\|\ge (K-\epsilon)$

and by $1,2$ we conclude that $\|M_g\| = K$

Comment: You need to prove the other inequality or find a function so that the norm is attained

Comment: The 2nd should be very easy..

Comment: yes, I can do the 2nd, but wondered to know where is the flaw in what I wrote? 

Also using the other def, 
$$\|M_g\| = \sup \{ \|M_gf\|_{L^p}  \ \ \ : \|f\|_{L^p} \le 1 \} = K = \|g\|_{L^\infty}  $$
so why do we need the two inequalities and not this?

Comment: how do you know thats the supremum?

Comment: So since $\|f\|_{L^p} \le 1$ then $\|M_gf\|_{L^p} $ can at most be $K$ by $(\ast)$. Is it wrong? Can you elaborate that why it might not be supremum?

Comment: You showed its an upper bound, not the least upper bound..